# Randomly Generating a 2d/3d Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, random

I've thought about this for awhile but what is maybe a good way to go about randomly generating a 2-d or possibly 3-d array. Im not looking for specific code per se, but more just a general idea or way one might think of doing it.

edit: Sorry I mistyped, What I meant is say you have an array (2d or 3d) filled with empty space, and I wanted to randomly generate Char *'s in it......randomly(everything else would be blank). is what I meant.

Comment: you mean other than a for loop calling rand?

Comment: What do you want to do. Create an array or generate random numbers.

Comment: I think he might be wanting to make an array or a random size, not just filling an array of fixed size with random data

Comment: what do you mean by char*'s ? strings?

Comment: What have you thought of before?  What are your concerns?  What is your object layout that you require.  It's not hard to populate a structure with random data, so either you're thinking too hard, or you've got extra requirements you haven't included in the question, and ideas of how to solve it that are stumping you, but you have not relayed.  The more info, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were trying to sparsely fill a large 2D array with uppercase ASCII characters it would be something like the following in C:

```
int array[A][B];

for (int i = 0; i < SOMETHING; ++i)
{
          //Note: Modulus will not give perfect random distributions depending on 
          //the values of A/B but will be good enough for some purposes.
     int x = rand() % A;  
     int y = rand() % B;

     char ch = rand() % 26 + 'A';
     array[x][y] = ch;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. create a 2D/3D array
2. Fill it with random data
3. ?????
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a bunch of random values using `rand()` and arrange them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the randomness to have continuity in 2 or 3 dimensions, the concept you're looking for is "noise".

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't want the whole code, but it's really not that much code.

```
int array[A][B][C];
std::generate_n(array[0][0], A*B*C, rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int *ary,   /* Array */
    x_size, /* X size of the array */
    y_size; /* Y size of the array */

x = rand() % MAX_SIZE;
y = rand() % MAX_SIZE;

ary = malloc(sizeof(int) * (x * y));

ary[1][1] = 1;
```

If the [][] indexing doesn't work, you may need to use

```
*(ary + (x_size * X_COORD) + Y_COORD)
```

to access element `[X_COORD][Y_COORD]`. I'm not completely sure whether c99 supports that syntax.

Sorry, I couldn't think of a way to say it without code.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion - thought you needed a random size array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer you asked for, but could prove useful anyway.  Sometimes when I want to generate a large random string, I do the following:
1. generate a small random string, say 3 or 4 characters in length
2. get its hash with your algorithm of choice (MD5, SHA1, etc)

In this way you can generate quite long 'randoms' strings.  Once you have the very long random string you can split it up into smaller ones or use it whole.  The integrity of the randomness is based on how random the short initial string is.